# Sencha Touch 2 : Button to push a new view in a navigationBar of a navigationView

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i try to add a button in a navigationBar of a navigationView with possibility to push a new view when i tap the button. I need help because i don't understand how i can do that. My button is ok and i can log tap action in my console but i can't push a new view. I need to have a view which is docked to my tabbar... 
What i want in fact is proposing to user the possibility to change the view : with the button he could switch views : navigation / list to carousel (with same datas from a store). All is ok with navigationview and my list of results but i can't add the carousel view possibility by tapping the button...

My first question would be, is it possible ? If yes then how can i do that ?

My code :

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Annuaire", {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

xtype: 'annuairepanel',

requires: [
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.Store'
],

config: {
    /*IMPORTANT : évite une erreur de clsReplace...*/
    autoDestroy: false,
    title: 'Annuaire',
    iconCls: 'address_book',
    defaultBackButtonText: 'Retour',

            navigationBar: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'carousel-annuaire',
            iconCls: 'more',
            iconMask: true,
            align: 'right',
            listeners: {
                'tap': function() {
                        console.log('tap !');
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    },

    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        id: 'liste-annuaire',
        cls: 'x-liste-annuaire',
        itemTpl: [ 
                 '<div class="vignette-liste" style="background-image:url({_ann_www_pub});"></div>',
                 '<div class="titre-liste">{post_title}</div>',
                 '<div class="categories-liste">{categories}</div>'
                 ].join(''),
        title: 'Annuaire',
        grouped:true,
        indexBar:true,

    store: 'Annuaires',                                    
    }
    ]

}});
```

Thanks for your help

Ben

Comment: welcome to SO. Please clarify, what exact do you want? You could edit your post

Answer (score 0):

Do you not confusing why NavigationView is used for? The use case for it is create a stacked pool of Panels (Ext.Panel and/or Ext.form.Panel) and do navi.push(view)/navi.pop() to easy navigating in eg. Master-Detail relation.

First it is not intended to add a List as a direct child of the Navi View.

Also the good practice is using of the Sencha **MVC** Controllers. I'm advising you to start with reading basic concepts in Sencha doc page: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers , http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/views and other guides.

I do not say there are perfect Getting Start sources but there is something. 
If you want to get more close look at Sencha buy a commercial book.

*Tip, never buy Jesus Garcia's books*

I'd prefer issues from **Packt** Publishers.

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your answer. I did what i wanted with this piece of code. `code`                listeners: {
     'tap': function() {
      
      var view = Ext.create('MyApp.view.AnnuaireCarousel');
          if (!view.getParent()) {
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
      }
       view.show();
       this.hide();
     }
    }

Comment: I used sencha touch 2 examples to realize my first App. I think all is not perfect but it works. I'm looking for a good book but i don't find a good one about Sencha Touch 2 for the moment... Thanks again Oleg!